# Clicking links in content not working (non css issue)

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have a Wordpress + Webpack theme with a custom post type archive page for careers. **Problem is that none of the links are clickable in the content** (breacrumbs (yoast module), content links, post permalinks). The issue appeared recently. The header menu works fine.

**So far I've tried:**

- removing the content text: no effect
- remove post listing to see if the issue is related to the listing only
- Tried moving the post loop to another template: still not clickable
- absolute position css to see if anything is overlapping: no effect
- remove all styles, leave only html: no effect
- disabling all plugins: no effect.

  - oddly it works from time-to-time on safari but cant see a logic in it (but not firefox, opera, chrome)
  - Issue is not present on local install either (codebase for theme is the same)

The jobs listing archive template looks as follows:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Jobs  */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
  <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
      <div class="page-content">  

        <div class="jobs-listing">
          <div class="blob-wrap">
            <div class="blob blob-right-top"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/page-blob_4.svg" alt="NEXD Blob"></div>
            <div class="blob blob-left-top is-hidden-mobile"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/blog-blob.svg" alt="NEXD Blob"></div>
            <div class="blob blob-left-bottom"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/table-blob-left.svg" alt="NEXD Blob"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="positions-wrap above-fold_wrap">
              <div class="container positions-container">

                  <div class="breadcrumbs">
                        <?php if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) { yoast_breadcrumb('<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>'); } ?>
                  </div><!-- breadcrumbs -->
                  <div class="columns is-centered" data-aos="fade-up">
                      <div class="column">
                          <div class="positions-title has-text-centered columns is-centered">
                            <div class="column is-8">
                              <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                                  <?php the_content(); ?>
                              <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                              <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/scroll-mouse--blue.svg" alt="Scroll icon">
                            </div>
                          </div><!-- title -->
                              <div class="positions columns">
                                  <?php $args = array(
                                      'post_type' => 'jobs',
                                      'posts_per_page' => -1,  //show all posts
                                      );
                                  $posts = new WP_Query($args); if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
                                      <div class="column">
                                          <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="Read more about <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>">
                                          <div class="positions-inner">
                                              <div class="position-title">
                                                  <h3><?php  echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="position-link">
                                                  <span><?php the_field('starting_from'); ?></span>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="position-locations">
                                                  <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/icon-map--pin.svg" alt="map-pin"><span class="location-name"><?php the_field('location'); ?></span>
                                              </div>
                                          </div>
                                          </a>
                                      </div>
                                  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                                  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                              </div>
                          </div><!-- column is-10 -->
                      </div><!-- columns -->
              </div><!-- container -->
          </div><!-- positions -->
        </div><!-- jobs listing-->

      </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- .content-area -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

When I switch to the common template, all links in content work and rest of the site is fine.

View [here](https://www.nexd.com/jobs)

Answer (score 0):

I test your website, if you click the link before an external/internal source is loaded the link work.
So you have 2 option, try to find which of that source block your link or use this code for exceed the problem:

```
<div class="column">
<div class="positions-inner">
<a href="https://www.nexd.com/career/technical-writer/" title="Read more about 
 Technical Writer">    
<div class="position-title">
<h3>Technical Writer</h3>
</div>
<div class="position-link">
<span>ASAP</span>
</div>
<div class="position-locations">
<img src="https://www.nexd.com/wp-content/themes/nexd_theme/assets/icon-map--pin.svg" 
alt="map-pin"><span class="location-name">Tallinn, Estonia</span>
</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

This is with php code:

```
 <div class="column">

   <div class="positions-inner">
  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="Read more about <?php echo 
  get_the_title(); ?>">
   <div class="position-title">
    <h3><?php  echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>
       </div>
           <div class="position-link">
       <span><?php the_field('starting_from'); ?></span>
         </div>
       <div class="position-locations">
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/icon-map--pin.svg" alt="map-pin"><span class="location-name"><?php the_field('location'); ?></span>
  </div>
  </a>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Code change moving the link element into the inner div unfortunately didn't work

Comment: I tried with g.console and work fine with that code. must play with that for same result ( edited with php code)